# Make owner of an enterprise application if the user got application developer role in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I got many enterprise apps in Azure production, deployed all the app using Ansible and Graph API. I want to make my user as the owner of all this apps using API, my user already got only the application developer role.

I tried assigning the enterprise app owner using graph API, output shows success. unfortunately from GUI my user is still not an owner of that app.

I guess this issue is with the role I got for the user. Any input to solve this issue?

Comment: Hello @hashimvayalar, I hope that you are using this `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/owners/$ref` to add the user as a owner to the enterprise application..

Comment: I have used v1.0. Tested now and it works when i use beta. Let me use in ansible code, hope this works. Thank you @AnsumanBal-MT

Comment: Glad to be of help @hashimvayaler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding owner to a enterprise application using the below API for a owner where the user doesn't even have the `Application Developer Role` assigned to it .

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{SPobjectid}/owners/$ref
Request Body:
{
"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/userobjectId"
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Note:** It was also the same if I assigned the user `Application Developer` as a Active assignment in assigned roles.

---

If you are using the below API then the **user will be added to owners** section in the `App registration blade`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appregobjectId/owners/$ref
Request Body:
{
"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/userobjectId"
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]