# REST API for adding Enterprise Application's owner in AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When i want to add `app owner` to `Azure App Registration` i am calling this `PS` script:

```
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId "app registration object id" -RefObjectId "user object id"
```

But how to add `Enterprise application` user id as owner using Rest API or `az cli` or Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Enterprise application user-id as owner, you can make use of [**Microsoft Graph API**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

To run the query, make sure to have the below **[permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)** consented:

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and added the user-id as owner successfully after executing the below query by [Ansuman Bal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70112594/make-owner-of-an-enterprise-application-if-the-user-got-application-developer-ro).***

Please **note** that, **`Sri`** is a user of Enterprise Application before executing the  query:

[image]

##### Query:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{Your_EnterpriseApp_Objectid}/owners/$ref

Request Body:
{
"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/UserObjectId"
}
```

##### Response:

[image]

**After running above query, `Sri` added as owner successfully in the Portal like below**:

[image]

##### Update:

You can also make use of below **Powershell** Script to add Owner to your Enterprise Application:

```
$EnterpriseId = 'Your Enterprise App ObjectID'
$UserId = 'User ObjectID'
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $EnterpriseId -RefObjectId $UserId
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Owner added successfully"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appriciate the effort, but i really need to use `servicePrincipal` with so high privilige with `Directory read all`?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. You can also use **PowerShell** to add owner to Enterprise Application.